# Iteration error in Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, iteration

When I tried to select items from the item list using Excel sheet through Java environment, only the first item is selected and executed. The next set of iteration is not happening.

```
int i=1;

while (i<=sheet.getLastRowNum()  )  
{

    row = sheet.getRow(i);

    String w = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    //  Processing : logic on "items" from excel 

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about next column of the row ? Because you iterate over a row of column. Since this is a matrix, you should also use another inner loop for columns. That could be sheet.getRow(i).getLastColumnNum()

Comment: a) cell  is (Zero) always and  Row is changing .
b) Retrieving one element from a column in excel , applying logical task.
c) Retrieving 2nd element from a column in excel applying logical task and     so on....

Comment: Which library are you using for reading from excel ? Have you checked the value of lastRowNum ?

Comment: a ) Apache POI 
b) It automatically stops at null cell and gets the count of stored data in table column or printed data.  
c) However even if i give the last row no. as CONDITION it does not retrieve the data from excel.

Comment: Try using `int rowsNum = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); `

Comment: The Logical Task Code here.


char[] ch = w.toCharArray();

int y = w.length();

for (int m = y ; m <= y; m--)

{
  
     String pl1 = new String(ch,0,m);

     if(pl1.length()>=2)

     {
        
      char[] dh = new char[y];
      
 int c=y-1;

       int g = y-1;

       int h = 1;
     
       for (int j=c; j<=y; j--) 

    {

        if(m>2&&h<=8)

        {

         String mpm  = new String(dh,0,y);

            dh[g] = ch[j];
           String pl = new String(ch,0,m);
                   --m;
                   h++;
              g--;
                k++;
..      ..... ......
 }

Comment: So lets clarify it, do you want to reset the value of the column after getting information or analyzing the content ? Please recheck this example for using the POI http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Comment: using: -  int rowsNum = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); 
String w = rowsNum.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();


err : Cannot invoke getCell(int) on the primitive type int

Comment: to Vira....
I dont want to reset the values in excel , but i want to retrieve each value one by one from a column in excel say 0th column ,and apply logical task on each values using for loop or while loop.

Comment: part of the code i have sent in comment rest in answer space.

Answer (score 0):

OK then try this sample firstly before your code. Check every column and row is visited. Maybe better way is using Iterators.

```
try {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

    //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

    //Get first sheet from the workbook
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        //For each row, iterate through each columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    file.close();
    FileOutputStream out = 
        new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I think you are fetching values from excel sheet and forming another excel sheet transferring the data to other...and printing them as well.

Comment: Doesnt matter, important part of the code is reading from row & cell.

Comment: a) Reading is being done ,that is not the issue .
b) Reading each  row (i) cell(0)   logical task is to be applied on each String value in excel sheet .   
c) Logical task is to split all the string values one by one from excel , storing       prefix and suffix in D Base using for loop.

Comment: a) Word list is there in excel...so row(i) cell(o )  that is one column in excel.
b) Now a List is there in excel agree....with one column only ...  
c) Read each cell apply logical task again read another cell apply logical task ...
d) Meaning to say row is changing cell (0) always

Comment: Then what is your issue ? I read your question again, you said you cannot go through the second row's first column. Isnt' that your question ?

Comment: Logical task is splitting each word into its stem list and suffix list and insert them in table in data base through J D B C .

Comment: Reading from Excel      (    Logical task           )                 to My S q l 
example : tiger , oranges , .... in excel 
read tiger      ti / ger    again  oranges  ora / nges...   like that whole column Excel must be Done  ....

Comment: try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbase","root","ALPHAS");
con.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement pstm = null ;
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:\\fileLoad.xlsx");

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row row;
for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)//
{
row = sheet.getRow(i);
String wd = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();